# Function for multiple correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation

In R, is it possible to find multiple correlation matrix?

Any package/in-built function available?

Is it possible to specify order of correlations in cor()?

Comment: @Richard Scriven can you specify the how to add order in cor() in r?  and how to find multiple correlation?

Answer (score 3):

The base R function `cor()` produces a multiple correlation matrix.

The order of variables in its output will mimic their order in the data frame to which you apply it, so arrange your data frame, then apply `cor()`. Here's an example using piping in `dplyr` so you don't actually modify the stored data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(10), y = rev(seq(10)), z = seq(10))
df %>%
    select(z, y, x) %>% # Use select() to reorder variables in df
    cor(.)
```

Result:

```
   z  y  x
z  1 -1  1
y -1  1 -1
x  1 -1  1
```

Comment: Is `dplyr` really necessary here? Can't we just `cor(df)`? Or `cor(df[c("z", "y", "x")])` if you wish?

Comment: No, not necessary, just where my head went. Your second option does the same with less fuss.

Comment: It's Ok, in general this is a nice and compact solution.

Comment: isn't it single correlation function if I am not wrong?

Comment: @ulfelder cor() function produces zero order correlation, i.e., z on z, z on y, z on x, y on z, y on y, etc. But I want first order correlation, z on x&y, y on z&x and x on z&y combined. is that possible?

Comment: I don't know of such a statistic. The package `ppcor` offers `pcor.test()` to consider the partial correlation of two variables, controlling for a third (e.g., x and y, conditional on z). To consider x on y + z, though, I think you'd need to run a regression.